# Some relations returning NULL when using UUID as ID - Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, laravel-9

Why do some of my voucher relations return null? even though there is a voucher with that ID
[image: image of error proof]

And some relationships run well as in the picture below
[image]

**This is code for dumping the results**

```
dump(\App\Models\AffiliatorVoucher::find('27a4093d-2370-4c55-bc44-1f8ef8144067')->toArray());
dd(\App\Models\AffiliatorVoucherMember::with('voucher')->find(172)->toArray());
```

**App\Models\AffiliatorVoucher**

```
class AffiliatorVoucher extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    protected $guarded = [
        'id',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'detail' => 'object',
    ];

    public $incrementing = false;


    public function members() :HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AffiliatorVoucherMember::class);
    }

    // ... other methods
}
```

**App\Models\AffiliatorVoucherMember**

```
class AffiliatorVoucherMember extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    
    protected $casts = [
        'detail' => 'object',
    ];

    
    public function voucher() :BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(AffiliatorVoucher::class, 'affiliator_voucher_id');
    }
}
```

**Affiliator Vouchers Migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('affiliator_vouchers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->foreignId('affiliator_id')->constrained()->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('organization_id')->nullable()->constrained()->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('prefix')->nullable();
        $table->string('code')->unique();
        $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(1);
        $table->bigInteger('discount_amount')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->decimal('discount_percentage', 5, 2)->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->json('detail')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

**Affiliator Voucher Member Migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('affiliator_voucher_members', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignUuid('affiliator_voucher_id')->constrained()->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('unique_id')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->nullable();
        $table->json('detail');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

For additional information, I'm using `\Str::uuid()` for inserting the id, and I'm working on **Laravel ^9.19**.

Thank you in advance for the answers friends who helped answer this problem. ❤️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the documentation on handling models with UUIDs as primary keys:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#uuid-and-ulid-keys

It surely will fix any issue you have.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful if the field that is being created with the relation is UUid not Integer, because as the uuid is of large logitudes in an interge does not give space.

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->uuid('user_id'); // Llave foránea
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```